# In Ian Goodfellow et al's paper "Generative Adversarial Networks", why do they specify that they do not need a Markov chain or inference network?

Tags: markov-process, generative-models, gan

In Ian Goodfellow et al's paper [*Generative Adversarial Networks*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661), they state, "There is no need for any Markov chains or unrolled approximate inference networks during either training or generation of samples." Why would there be a need for a Markov Chain or unrolled approximate inference network? What would, or traditionally have, each of these approaches offered in statistical analysis and/or machine learning?

Comment: This is just a guess, so I'm not writing an answer. But sampling from a generative probability model in a Bayesian context means estimating a posterior predictive distribution; when this distribution is not "nice," it's typical to use MCMC or related methods to simulate the quantities of interest. So I think that Goodfellow is writing this sentence to distinguish the operation of a GAN from thematically similar generative models.

Answer (score 2):

Two other popular generative models which I think he is referring to are:

1. Variational autoencoders, which have an encoder network, $q_\theta(z|x)$ which approximates the posterior distribution on latent codes (the "inference network").
2. Restricted Boltzmann Machines, which require block gibbs sampling between visible and hidden units to sample an image (or even just to train the model).